# Error converting urlencode from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, .net, urlencode

I have a class in PHP that encodes this code "`?�m�U`", using `urlencode()`, resulting in "`%3F%B6%16m%BEU`". However, when I try to encode with `c#` uisng `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`, the result is not the same. The method in c# has a second parameter "`Encoding.SOMETHING`". I've tried each one of the possible paramaters, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What is `?�m�U` supposed to represent (or is it an error in the submission of the question)?  If it represents binary data, base64 encoding the data first might be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work:

```
string utf8Encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YOURURL, Encoding.UTF8);
```